# How to save the changeable data using Realm?

Tags: android, realm

In my application I use realm database. As you know, the data is saved in objects, like this:

```
Allergen first_item = new Allergen();
first_item.setName("FirstItem");
first_item.setDescription("Description");
```

I have a list of names and descriptions, that the user can edit, delete or add. How can I store and show this data again when the user has edited this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initialize in MainApplication

```
 Realm.init(getApplicationContext());
        RealmConfiguration config = new RealmConfiguration
                .Builder()
                .deleteRealmIfMigrationNeeded()
                .build();
        Realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
```

Then add Below code to save.

```
 try(Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()) {
     realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                @Override
                public void execute(Realm realm) {

                    realm.insertOrUpdate(first_item );
                }
            });
 }
```